# How can I clear keyboard focus on a page when I exit and return?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms (3.4) app with several Content pages, some of which have several entry boxes.  If go to a page, then edit an entry, so far everything is fine.  But when I "exit" the page (by doing a Navigation.PopModalAsync() ), and then return to the page, on iOS there is immediately a cursor in the entry, and also the keyboard pops-up.  This is not what my user will expect.

On Android, the cursor is in the entry, but it does not pop up the keyboard automatically.  This too is not desireable.

For refernce, on UWP it doesn't show focus when returning to the page.

How can I avoid this behavior?  Is there a way to have the page "clear" the focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
override protected void OnAppearing()
{
  entry.Unfocus();
}
```

Comment: So, if I have 6 entry boxes (I do), I would call Unfocus()  on each?

Comment: What you request is against Human interface guidelines and you would have to do the same on iOS in the native interface too. Obviously you may try to focus some other control if you have it, or track which entry is last focused and remove focus from it. There isn't one line code solution unless you have something that will accept the focus and won't display the keyboard.